# Redirect on login

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I am trying to redirect back to my index.php page after logging in, but I am having trouble with it.

Here is my login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!=""){
    header("home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($row['password']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("home.php");
    }else{
    ?>
    <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
    <?php
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

Here is my navbar in my index.php:

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-left">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#" style="font-family: Warnes">Unleasht</a>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#music" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <?php
            function loggedIn(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="")
            { echo '<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'. $_SESSION['username'] .'<span class="caret"></span></a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a href="#login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login" id="loginbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>';
                }
            }
            loggedIn();
            ?>

        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

But neither of them are in the same files. The location of the login.php is in assets/php/login/login.php

Could I get some help?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `Location:` in setting header to redirect.

You have to change `header("home.php");` to `header("Location: home.php");`

Comment: It's still not working. And I tried changing it to    header("Location: ../../../index.php")